# Performing operation on each element of a list, returning a Flowable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I'm working with RxJava, in Kotlin.

I have a function, `transform(f: Foo): Single<Bar>`

How can I take a `List` of `Foo`s, and perform `transform` on each of them, to get a result of `Flowable<Bar>`, where each `next` in the `Flowable` is the results of calling `transform`?

Basically, I need a function

```
fun getFlowable(foos: List<Foo>): Flowable<Bar> {
    // Runs transform() on each element of foos
    // Concatenates the results to the flowable.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
fun getFlowable(foos: List<Foo>, transform: (Foo) -> Bar): Flowable<Bar> =
        Flowable.fromIterable(foos.map(transform))
```

or better version

```java
fun getFlowable(foos: List<Foo>, transform: (Foo) -> Bar): Flowable<Bar> =
        Flowable.fromIterable(foos).map(transform)
```